# Highlighting aligned equation lines using tcolorbox

Tags: equations, align, tcolorbox, nesting

In my first box I've shown the three lines of math I want to display. I then wish to highlight the first and the last lines according to the design of box A and box B, seen below.

Is it possible to do this while still maintaining the aligned equation signs?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=1pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2}
\newtcbox{\highlight}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2,boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=1.6pt,auto outer arc,boxsep=-2pt,no shadow}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\def \epc {6.241 509 074 460 76 E18}
\def \cpe {1.602 176 634 E-19}

\begin{document}

\section*{Electric Charge}

I want to insert box A and box B within a bigger parent box in such a fashion that the equations in the smaller boxes align with each other's equation signs.

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10,colframe=black!30!yellow!20]\small
\begin{align*}
    \SI{\cpe}{\coulomb}                                &= \SI{1}{\elementarycharge} \leftarrow \text{\bf box A here} \\
    \frac{\SI{\cpe}{\coulomb}}{\num{\cpe}}             &= \frac{\SI{1}{\elementarycharge}}{\num{\cpe}} \\
    \text{\bf box B here} \rightarrow \SI{1}{\coulomb} &= \SI{\epc}{\elementarycharge} \\
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\textbf{Box A:}
\begin{empheq}[box=\highlight{red!30!yellow!40}{black!30!red!30!yellow}]{align*}\small
    \SI{\cpe}{\coulomb} &= \SI{1}{\elementarycharge}
\end{empheq}

\textbf{Box B:}
\begin{empheq}[box=\highlight{red!30!yellow!40}{black!30!red!30!yellow}]{align*}\small
    \SI{1}{\coulomb} &= \SI{\epc}{\elementarycharge}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that for this it might be better to use `hf-tikz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do not take this answer too seriously. I do not believe that there is an easy solution with `tcolorbox` and `empheq` "only", but I may well be wrong. Then there is the very nice package `hf-tikz`, which will allow you to highlight the parts of the equations that you want to highlight. However, I do not know how to teach it to use `copy shadow` which I am using here to emulate your box. So I use "just" `tikzmark` to add these boxes. One of the many amazing features of `tikzmark` is that you can use the marks in a seemingly "causality violating" way, i.e. you can use them before you define them. This works by writing the information in the aux file, which is why you have to compile more than once (three times here).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shadows}
\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=1pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2}
\newtcbox{\highlight}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2,boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=1.6pt,auto outer arc,boxsep=-2pt,no shadow}
\tikzset{highlight/.style 2 args={fill=#1,draw=#2,thick,rounded corners=1.6pt,
double copy shadow={shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=-0.4pt},inner xsep=1ex,
minimum height=1.4em,yshift=0.35em},
mylight/.style={highlight={red!30!yellow!40}{black!30!red!30!yellow}}}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\def\epc{6.241 509 074 460 76 E18}
\def\cpe{1.602 176 634 E-19}

\begin{document}
\section*{Electric Charge}

I want to insert box A and box B within a bigger parent box in such a fashion that the equations in the smaller boxes align with each other's equation signs.

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10,colframe=black!30!yellow!20]\small%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\iftikzmark{lhs1}{%
  \node[fit=(pic cs:lhs1)(pic cs:rhs1),mylight]{};}{%
  \typeout{Please recompile.}}
\iftikzmark{lhs2}{%
  \node[fit=(pic cs:lhs2)(pic cs:rhs2),mylight]{};}{%
  \typeout{Please recompile.}}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{align*}
     \tikzmark{lhs1}\SI{\cpe}{\coulomb}  &=                              
     \SI{1}{\elementarycharge}\tikzmark{rhs1}\\[0.2em]
    \frac{\SI{\cpe}{\coulomb}}{\num{\cpe}}             &= \frac{\SI{1}{\elementarycharge}}{\num{\cpe}} \\[0.2em]
    \tikzmark{lhs2}\SI{1}{\coulomb} &=
    \SI{\epc}{\elementarycharge}\tikzmark{rhs2} \\
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me mention that `tikzmark` has even more amazing features. In particular, it has the `save nodes` key which allows one to save complete nodes (rather than "just" marks) to some file. In principle one can use this to find an even more automatic solution. I will leave this for another day.

Comment: Very creative! But for some reason, copying this MWE over to Overleaf, it won't compile?

Comment: @Matt This is most likely because overleaf uses an older LaTeX installation, which does not have the latest version of `tikzmark`. I added a version that should (!) work with overleaf.

Comment: It does compile in Overleaf.

Comment: @Cragfelt Thanks! I rewrote the code in such a way that it does. Here the most important ingredient is the good old `\tikzmark` command.